# Which is the correct sentence?

Tags: word-usage

Which one of the the following is correct?

> We have many car in our showroom.

or

> We have lots of cars in our showroom.

Answer (score 3):

> We have many car in our showroom.

The above sentence is wrong. You could say something like this,

> We have many cars in our showroom.

Your second sentence is technically correct.

Using *many* or *lots of* requires a plural noun, therefore, "car" would never be correct, only "cars". And *lots of* is usually considered the more informal of the two – suitable for everyday conversation, but less likely to be found in a news article or technical paper.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that using _many_ or _lots of_ requires a plural noun, therefore, _car_ would never be correct, only _cars_. I think it's also worth mentioning that _lots of_ is usually considered the more informal of the two – suitable for everyday conversation, but less likely to be found in a news article or technical paper.

Comment: @ J.R changes made.

Comment: Note that "lots of" can also take a mass noun, as in "There is lots of wisdom on Stack Exchange."